# Optimal control of retries in fopen

Tags: c, algorithm, fopen

I'm using retries when trying to open a file in C, and I would like to know if this way is an adequate implementation, it seems a bit untidy for me .

```
while(openRetry<=3){
    fp = fopen(lgConfig.lgFlHndl.fileName, "rb");
    if(fp==NULL){
        if(openRetry<3){
            openRetry++;
        }
        else{
            if (LogFile_Reconstruct(&lgConfig)){
                ret=1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                ret=0;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
         ret=1;
         break;
    }
}
```

I will appreciate any improvements or some reference to more tidy algorithms

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 as IDE
Thank you

Comment: Without doing anything to alleviate the issue, what's the purpose of the retry?

Comment: It was a requirement of the team manager, the file is located in an SD card, so I supposed It will prevent some temporary access problem

Comment: @FerMirabelli Temporary as in a few nanoseconds? Shouldn't there be some sort of delay before attempting to open the same file again?

Comment: Inserting a sleep() call inside the if(openRetry<3) call may be benificial - otherwise it would be running extremely fast and call LogFile_Reconstruct() frequently. Also, do you only want to retry 3 times? I assume the 'ret' variable is responsible for run the whole retry process?

Comment: Thank you @squeamishossifrage and schil227 , I will add some sleep time between cycles, and the ret variable is for the return value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some what cleaner code, at least in my opinion. But this is just to illustrate my idea.

```
ret = 0;
while (openretry <= 3) {
    fp = fopen(lgConfig.lgFlHndl.fileName, "rb");

    if (fp) {
        ret = 1;
        break;
    }

    openRetry++;
    if(openRetry == 4) {
        ret = LogFile_Reconstruct(&lgConfig));      
        break;
    }

    sleep/yield(some millsecs); //Should have some delaying mechanism
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the improvment @Ritesh , it seems cleaner for me too

Comment: @Fer . Also you can change "<= 3" to "<4" as 4 gives an impression that you are trying for 4 times (0-3). <=3 gives reader, an impression that you are doing retry for 3 times. And if you plan to change, then you have change that inner if condition also. This is just an opinion. But I am glad that I could be of some help.

Comment: the posted code contains a 'magic' number or two.  Suggest giving that 'magic' number a meaningful name, like: `#define MAX_TRIES (4)` then using that `MAX_TRIES` throughout the code.

Comment: Agreed, Rather than using numeric constant, use macros as suggested.